# do i need to use latest plugins to fix UIWebview issue?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, uiwebview, app-store, ionic4

My ionic ios app is rejected due to UIWebView issue(ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage) in app store. I am using following plugins in my app.

fcm-with-dependecy-updated(v2.4.0), facebook4(v5.0.0), x-socialsharing(v5.4.7), googleplus(v7.0.1)

do i need to update these plugins to latest versions to solve UIWebView issue?
when i use latest versions of these plugins get following errors

```
'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found   
'firebasecore/firebasecore.h' file not found  
'GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h' file not found
```

anyone know how can i solve this issue.

Comment: you can try with adding latest platform like so `ionic cordova platform add ios@latest`

Comment: i am using cordova ios 5.1.1. tried 6.0.0 also. still issue is there

Comment: ah then a plugin is having old UIwebview

Comment: @AthifShaffy yeah. older versions of fcm, facebook4, googleplus plugins are using UIebView. I have fixed by using new versions

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use

> https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex

this firebase plugin has issues resolved with the latest UIWebView for Ionic iOS.

Also, add inside config.xml

```
<platform name="ios">
  <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
      <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
      </feature>
  <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</platform>
```